# Removal of N Random nodes from the graph in R

Tags: r, igraph

I am new to R/igraph. I would like to remove N nodes randomly from a graph. However, I could not find the right way to do that. I have generated the Erdos-Renyi graph with the help of the igraph package with 400 vertices.

igraph provides the deletion of the vertices, but not in the random way.
For example: `delete.vertices(graph, v)`.

I referred to [this](http://igraph.org/r/doc/graph.structure.html) documentation.

I also searched the web and previous questions on Stack Overflow, but could not get the right answer.

Can anyone please tell or refer me to documentation on how to remove the N (lets say N = 100) random nodes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you just need to generate a vector of random numbers ranging from 1 to 400:

```
random.deletes <- runif(n=100, min=1, max=400)
```

And then apply it:

```
my.new.graph <- delete.vertices(graph, random.deletes)
```

Of course, both can be done at once but you'd lose track of the deleted nodes:

```
my.new.graph <- delete.vertices(graph, runif(n=100, min=1, max=400))
```